# CentOS 7 mount ebs thorugh systemd unit

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, centos7

CentOS 7 HVM community image is not mounting the drive if as recommended we do it via rc.local(since doing it via /etc/fstab entry may halt the machine and make it not reachable if any issue occurs in mounting during boot). We have set the permission of /etc/rc.local as executable but still it is mounting during boot process. Not sure what the issue is!

So, I am doing it via following systemd unit in /etc/systemd/system in file mountebs.service which is working fine

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount EBS Drives
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mount /dev/xvdb1 /var/www/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, is there something which I am providing extra here like `After=network.target` and can be taken off because all it just need to do is to mount the drive on system boot nothing else? Also, is it the best option to do it via systemd unit or something else more easier can be done?